# Convert a DataFrame into a list: type of elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe

Using Python, I am reading a column from an excel file:

```
df=pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx', sheet_name='comb', usecols ='A')
```

I convert that column into a list with:

```
col1 = list(df.values)
```

When I try to operate with this list called col1, I have a list of elements in which each element is an array of float64:

```
col1 = [array([39349999.9999999]), array([0.]), array([0.]),...,array([0.])]
```

On the other hand, I realised that if I add the header of the column in this way:

```
col2 = list(df['Power (W)'].values)
```

I obtain the same list called now col2, but each element is a float64 instead of an array.

```
col2 =[39349999.9999999, 0.0, 0.0,..., 0.0]
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In the first case

```
df=pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx', sheet_name='comb', usecols ='A')
col1 = list(df.values)
col1 = [array([39349999.9999999]), array([0.]), array([0.]),...,array([0.])]
```

you are converting the dataframe (2D matrix) into a list of list.

If you print the df you obtain the object array

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

if you convert the dataframe to a list you will obtain an array of ARRAY OBJECTS

```
print(list(df.values))
[array([1]), array([2]), array([3]), array([4]), array([5])]
```

BUT

if you convert the values of the pandas with `.tolist` you obtain a normal array of arrays

```
print(df.values.tolist())
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

### In the second case

`col2 = list(df['Power (W)'].values)`

you have selected one column so you have only a Series or array and when you convert it to a list, it becomes a 1 dimensional array list.

### to sum up

If you make a list of a df -> you have a 2 dimensional array/list

If you make a list of a column -> you have a 1 dimensional array/list